# Calculating Top N items per dimension

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I have the following query that shows total sales for each product on an hourly basis. However, it is very big data and I don't want to see all products, so would like to see the **top 1000 product_id** based on `sales` for each `date`, `hour`, and `category_id` dimensions.

```
SELECT date,
         hour,
         category_id,
         product_id,
         sum(sales) AS sales
FROM  a
LEFT JOIN 
    ON a.product_id = b.product_id
WHERE date(date) >= date('2021-01-01')
GROUP BY  1, 2, 3, 4
```

How to do it in the Athena?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`rank`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html#rank) function on your result and then filter out corresponding ranks:

```sql
SELECT date,
         hour,
         category_id,
         product_id,
         sales
FROM
(
    SELECT *,          
        rank() OVER (PARTITION BY date, hour, category_id
                    ORDER BY sales DESC) AS rnk
    FROM (your query)
)
WHERE rnk <= 1000
```

Comment: Hi @Guru, thanks for your response. The query gives the following error: Column 'hour' cannot be resolved. What do you think about it?

Comment: @datazang [this](https://pastebin.com/gXpV7MVy) works just fine. Not sure what are you missing in your query.